# error message: class interface or enum expected, what does this mean?

Tags: java

hello I get the error message:  class interface or enum expected, what does this mean?

my code:

```
/**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author (john) 
 * @version (22/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
private String phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
private int screensize;
    // memory card capacity
private int memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
private String mobileServiceProvider;
    // type of contract with service provider
private int mobileTypeOfContract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
private int chargeUp;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
private int switchedOnFor;
    // to simulate using phone for a period of time
private int charge;
    // checks the phones remaining charge
private String provider;
    // simulates changing the provider
private String GPS; 
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own


    // The constructor method

public Mobile(String mobilephonetype, int mobilescreensize,
int mobilememorycardcapacity, String mobileServiceProvider, int mobileTypeOfContract, int mobilecameraresolution, String mobileGPS, int chargeUp,int switchedOnFor, String changeProvider,int getBalance) {


    /**
*recieves orders for mobiles at the given price.
    */
this(yourCostHere);


price= 1000;
balance= 0;
total= 0;
 }

 /**
*returns a field price.
    */
public int getPrice()
   {
return price;
    }

    /**
    *return the amount of change due for orders of mobiles. 
    */
public int getBalance()
   {
return balance;
    }                


        //this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        //this.typeofcontract = 12;
        //this.checkcharge = checkcharge;
        //this.changeProvider = giffgaff;

  //Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(
 //   "Samsung" // String mobilephonetype
//,   1024    // intmobilescreensize
//,   2      // intmobilememorycardcapacity
//,   8       // intmobilecameraresolution
//,   "GPS"    //String mobileGPS
//,   "verizon" // String newserviceprovider
//,    "100" // intchargeUp
//,    "25" // intswitchedOnFor
//,    "25" // intcheckCharge
//,     "giffgaff"// String changeProvider
//);


        //typeofcontract = 12;
        //checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }
    //Mutator for newserviceprovider
public void setmobileServiceProvider(String newmobileServiceProvider)
   {
mobileServiceProvider = newmobileServiceProvider;
   }
   //Mutator for contracttype
public void setmobileTypeOfContract(int newmobileTypeOfContract)
   {
mobileTypeOfContract = newmobileTypeOfContract;
   }
   //Mutator for chargeUp
public void setchargeUp(int chargeUp)
   {
chargeUp = chargeUp;
   }
   //Mutator to simulate using phone for a period of time
public void switchedOnFor(int switchedOnFor)
   {
switchedOnFor = switchedOnFor;
    }
   //Accessor for type of phone
public String getType()
   {
returnphonetype;
   }
   //Accessor for provider
public String getprovider()
   {
returnmobileServiceProvider;
   }
   //Accessor for contract type
public int getContractType()
   {
returnmobileTypeOfContract;
   }
    //Accessor for charge
public int getCharge()
   {
returnchargeUp;
   }
    //Accessor which checks the phones remaining charge
public int checkCharge()
   {
returncheckCharge;
   }
    // simulates changing the provider
public void changeProvider()
   {
provider = changeProvider
   }

public int getBalance()
   {
return balance;
   }
    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
public void displayMobileDetails() {
System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);
System.out.println("mobileServiceProvider: " + mobileServiceProvider);
System.out.println("mobileTypeOfContract: " + mobileTypeOfContract );
} 

      /**
 * The mymobile class implements an application that
 * simply displays "new Mobile!" to the standard output.
 */
public class mymobile {
public void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("new Mobile!"); //Display the string.
    }
}
public static void buildPhones(){
Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung",3,4,"verizon",8,12,"GPS",100,25,"giffgaff");  
Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Samsung",3,4,"verizon",8,12,"GPS",100,25,"giffgaff");     
}    
public static void main(String[] args) {
buildPhones();
}  

}
```

any answers or replies and help would be greatly appreciated as I cant get it to compile like it did before with no syntax errors.

Comment: Which line produces that error?

Comment: The formatting on this code is immensely hard to read.

Comment: Please stop creating questions with huge amounts of code, and an error in a place that you don't specify. Ideally, cut the code down to *just* a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: sorry its this line: public void setmobileServiceProvider(String newmobileServiceProvider)
   {

Comment: You posted same type of question few minutes ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523808/error-illegal-start-of-expression-how-to-fix Remember to be a better developer, you need to learn debugging on your own.

Comment: This time you've got a stray closing brace before the method. If you indented all your code - or got an IDE to do it for you - you'd be able to see these problems much more easily.

Comment: also have a space for `returnphonetype` like `return phonetype`

Answer (score 1):

Besides your compiler error, there are others as well, e.g. this one:

```
public void switchedOnFor(int switchedOnFor)
{ 
  switchedOnFor = switchedOnFor;
}
```

This will have no effect, since the parameter `switchedOnFor` will shadow the member `switchedOnFor`, i.e. you assign the parameter to itself.

To fix that (and others like this) use `this.switchedOnFor = switchedOnFor;`. It might also be better to declare the parameter as final and thus let the compiler help you, because that assignment wouldn't compile anymore.

*Edit*: I'll summarize the errors reported in the comments, so please don't upvote me for them. It's just to provide a concise answer.

JonSkeet found the basic error:

```
public class Mobile
{
   ...
}
//Mutator for newserviceprovider
public void setmobileServiceProvider(String newmobileServiceProvider) { ...
```

The braces just before the method close the class and thus the method is defined outside a class, interface or enum, that's what the compiler tells you.

Raghunandan found this one:

```
public String getprovider()
{
  returnmobileServiceProvider;
}
```

The compiler will complain about `returnmobileServiceProvider` being unknown as well as a missing return statement. Here, a simple space is missing.

Another problem is your constructor (as hinted by Raghunandan):

```
public Mobile(String mobilephonetype, int mobilescreensize, int mobilememorycardcapacity, String mobileServiceProvider, int mobileTypeOfContract, int mobilecameraresolution, String mobileGPS, int chargeUp,int switchedOnFor, String changeProvider,int getBalance) {

  /**
   *recieves orders for mobiles at the given price.
   */
  this(yourCostHere);

  price= 1000;
  balance= 0;
  total= 0;
}
```

There are multiple issues here:

- the parameters are not used at all
- there is no other constructor that takes a single parameter (i.e. `this(yourCostHere);` won't compile)
- `yourCostHere` is an unknown symbol
- `getBalance` violates the naming convention, since `getXxx` implies a getter method

Some general advice stated above:

- formatting your code will help you spot errors
- using an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans will help you spot and fix errors
- learing how to debug your application (again easiest using an IDE) will help you to find runtime errors like the shadowing error above
- One of the most important points: **before you post questions, make sure your code is as correct and well formatted as it can get, then only post the relevant portions as well as necessary information on errors that occur (e.g. mark the line that the compiler/stacktrace indicates)**

Comment: and the constructor params are not right it should be 10 while it is 11 probably should get rid of `int getBalance` or add balance as param

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution: Use automatic code formatting. For example in eclipse: Contextmenue->Source->Format

Doing so, you will notice `setmobileServiceProvider` is defined outside the class block, which makes no sense. Move this method and any following inside the class block, and the error is gone.

Without a clean formatted code, it is impossible to understand such errors.